# How do I debug channel data in bot framework?

Tags: botframework

I have a bot where I've recently started passing channel data (user info) in from my directline client but now this makes it really hard to debug/test code that relies on this channel data.

Is there a way to have the Bot Framework Emulator send channel data or is there a better way to debug in this situation?

Comment: You can debug the direct line channel, or any channel, locally: https://blog.botframework.com/2017/10/19/debug-channel-locally-using-ngrok/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Emulator doesn't have an easy, built-in way to send custom `channelData`. There's a few different ways you can (kind of) do this, though:

#### Debug Locally

As @EricDahlvang mentioned (I forgot about this), you can [debug any channel locally](http://web.archive.org/web/20200722110139/https://blog.botframework.com/2017/10/19/debug-channel-locally-using-ngrok/)

#### WebChat

Emulator is built in [WebChat](https://github.com/Microsoft/BotFramework-WebChat), so the output will be the exact same. However, you miss some of the debugging functionality from Emulator.

1. Clone a [WebChat Sample](https://github.com/microsoft/BotFramework-WebChat/tree/54f67de4ff1740a050b2b5d9c07c3436e3ba314d/samples/15.a.backchannel-piggyback-on-outgoing-activities)
2. Edit `index.html` with `http://localhost:3978/api/messages` and your `channelData`
3. Run `npx serve`
4. Navigate to `http://localhost:5000`

#### Modify Messages In OnTurnAsync()

This would only be for testing/mocking purposes and you'd want to ensure this doesn't go into production, but you can modify incoming messages inside `OnTurnAsync()` and manually add the `channelData`.

Something like:

```
public async Task OnTurnAsync(ITurnContext turnContext, CancellationToken cancellationToken = default(CancellationToken))
{
    var activity = turnContext.Activity;

    activity.ChannelData = new
    {
        testProperty = "testValue",
    };
```

You could even make it happen with only specific messages, with something like:

```
if (turnContext.Activity.Text == "change channel data")
{
    activity.ChannelData = new
    {
        testProperty = "testValue",
    };
}
```

There's a lot of different options with this one, you just need to make sure it doesn't go into production.

Comment: Hello @mdrichardson, I didn't get this step: Edit index.html with http://localhost:3978/api/messages and your channelData , how exactly I do this as I found don't know which part i shoul replace

Comment: Check out [this sample](https://github.com/microsoft/BotFramework-WebChat/tree/master/samples/15.a.backchannel-piggyback-on-outgoing-activities). It shows how you can add custom `channelData` to activities being sent to the bot.